# get SignalStrength in dbm

Tags: android, signal-strength, dbm

I would like to show the the signal strength in dbm. But with my code i always become the result -1. But when i see the signal strength in the settings it's around -81..
Can you find a mistake? thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView dateAndTimeLabel;
    private int signalDBM = 0;

    public class GetParams extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override  
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            signalDBM = signalStrength.getEvdoDbm();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GetParams listener = new GetParams();
        TelephonyManager TelManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        TelManager.listen(listener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);             
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "CDMA signal strength is " + this.signalDBM, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
    }

    /* Create options menu etc*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> ```
> List<CellInfo> cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
>           //Checking if list values are not null
>             if (cellInfoList != null) {
>                 for (final CellInfo info : cellInfoList) {
>                     if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
>                         //GSM Network
>                         CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoGsm)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                         dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                         asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                     }
>                     else if (info instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
>                         //CDMA Network
>                         CellSignalStrengthCdma cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoCdma)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                         dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                         asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                     }
>                     else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
>                         //LTE Network
>                         CellSignalStrengthLte cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoLte)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                         dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                         asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                     }
>                     else if  (info instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
>                         //WCDMA Network
>                         CellSignalStrengthWcdma cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoWcdma)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                         dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                         asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                     }
>                     else{
>                         //Developed as a Cordova plugin, that's why I'm using callbackContext
>                         callbackContext.error("Unknown type of cell signal.");
>                     }
>                 }
>           }
> ```

If your cellphone is Samsung, it'll return 0 dBm, 0 asu. If not, then it should work (it worked in my Xperia M2 Aqua).