# Getting the 3G signal strength in Android

Tags: android, 3g, signal-strength

I'm currently detecting the technology my phone is connected to using, within a `onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)`, this code :

```
int networkType = telephonyManager.getNetworkType();
            switch (networkType) {
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                    return "3G-UMTS";
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                    return "3G-EVDO_0";
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                    return "3G-EVDO_A";
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                    return "3G-HSDPA";
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                    return "3G-HSUPA";
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                    return "3G-HSPA";
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
                    return "3G-EVDO_B";
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
                    return "3G-EHRPD";
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
                    return "3G-HSPAP";                  
                default:
                    return "Unknown";
            }
```

but once this verification is done, how do I manage to get the signal strength ?
I need to get the value (DBM or RSSI) only when the phone is under a 3G network.
Thanks

Comment: You can probably call `signalStrength.getLevel()` to get an abstract value, but for more detail, you'll need CellSignalStrengthWcdma, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27843845/1871033

Comment: I am always getting -113 Dbm using that method, which is kind of wired since I'm in a good coverage.
Despite I'm sure I am using a 3G communication, when I use `signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()`, I get some logical data. How does it come ?